# MYSQL query not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried everything. This is my last resort. The code below is supposed to submit the info received from the form to the database to be displayed later. Now I know the query is correct but it does not run. I am sure this is some sort of typo that I just don't see, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

    $blog = $_POST['blog_post'];
    $time = date('Y-m-d h-m-s');
    $id = $_SESSION['author_id'];
    if($blog != ""){
        $query = "INSERT INTO `blog`(`date`,`post`,`author_id`) VALUES('$time','$blog',$id)";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $row = mysqli_affected_rows($link);
        if($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)){
                        include 'header.php';
            $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            $url = rtrim($url, '/\\');
            $url .= '/blog.php'; 
            echo '<h3>Your blog has been posted. Go to <a style="color:white" href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';


            include 'footer.php';
        }else{
            echo "that didn't work";
        }
    }else{
        include 'header.php';
        echo '<h1>You did not enter a blog post. Please try again.';


        include 'footer.php';
    }
}else{
    redirect('index.php');   
}

?>
```

Comment: Seems you forgot a dot in `$url = rtrim($url, '/\\');` should probably read as `$url .= rtrim($url, '/\\');` give that a try and get back to me.

Comment: @Fred I did not concatenate because it is trimming the $url variable not adding to it. The next line is where I add information so I concatenate there. Is this wrong? I have only been programming for around a year or two so any help would be great.

Comment: @Jimbo I am using mysqli for all of my queries

Comment: @ZachBurdette Totally awesome, glad to hear ;) You should check out PDO!

Comment: If you're using mysqli already then take a look at mysqli prepared statements

Comment: have you CONNECTED to the db???

Comment: @Zach given that you've been programming for a year, have you at least tried my suggestion?

Comment: @Fred Just did...It didn't work.

Comment: @Sharky yes it is connected

Comment: @Zach are you sure you are getting `Date` value?Please echo the `$date` I think you are not getting the `date` value.

Comment: @Zach is your query coming in from a form? The problem may lie there.

Comment: @Deonia I have echoed the entire $query and the date is there. I then take and manually run the $query in SQL mode in phpmyadmin and it inserts correctly. So I know the $query works fine. This is be taken from a form but I get all of the info just fine no issues there. It just doesn't insert to the database

Comment: @Zach Something else I noticed, how is `$link` being defined?

Comment: @Fred in another file called sql_connect.php I checked to make sure of correct spelling and capitalizing and $link is correct.

Comment: At the insert query you single quote the other variable why not the id ?

Comment: @Zach check out Jonathan's suggestion about the `$id` not being in single quotes like the others.

Comment: Are you sure the variable $_POST['blog_post']; DOES NOT CONTAIN the quote character that will cause the query to brake? (Aw, welcome SQL injection)

Comment: @Sharky when I escape it it says that the post is blank.

Comment: @Zach please run your code and put just some letters in your $_POST['blog_post']. If it works, then its just an escaping problem. If you want to escape properly, then just use PDO and be a better man :) If it doesn't work even if you just use some letters in your $_POST['blog_post'] let us know to help further.

Comment: @Zach can you post your `$link`

Comment: `$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) OR die ('Could Not Connect.');` @Sharky I did that just before you commented and it still didn't work it sends a blank to the query.

Comment: can you post a few complete files up on say pastie.org without your credentials and we can beat on it

Comment: @DrewPierce How do I do that?

Comment: Please do the following: instead of having the variables VALUES('$time','$blog',$id) please write this VALUES('2013-05-09 13:57:27','hello i am a blog post','222') and execute the code. Please tell me if that is inserted. If not, then you are not connecting to the database. Also, why you are executing the query twice??? you have first time the line $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); and the second time the line if($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)){

Comment: go to pastie.org, paste in a .php or text. maybe a create table or two. maybe a few pasties  then post the url. that is if you aren't finding an answer here that solves it

Comment: @DrewPierce [http://pastie.org/private/dvyyf8sepevtjyhubg8lg] here is the link

Comment: if needed send me the missing php, it seems find except that the echo of the query string is missing author_id in the post.php but then again you did not send me the whole solution, so i cant pick it out of the SESSION[]

Comment: @Zach please check if your server supports mysqli. Try to change it to MySQL for testing.

Comment: @Deonia it has worked on all previous pages and still works on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then again maybe it is your entire script if you don't have **author_id** in your session variable because I got this to work (note the hardcode of author_id.

because your pastie did not include the php session variables in their ENTIRETY

the data was saved to the database.

```
<?php
    include 'sql_connect.php';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

        $blog = $_POST['blog_post'];
        $time = date('Y-m-d h-m-s');
        $id = $_SESSION['author_id'];
        $id=123;
        if($blog != ""){
            $query = "INSERT INTO `blog`(`date`,`post`,`author_id`) VALUES('$time','$blog',$id)";
            //echo $query;
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $row = mysqli_affected_rows($link);
            if($result){
            //               include 'header.php';
            //    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            //    $url = rtrim($url, '/\\');
            //    $url .= '/blog.php'; 
            //    echo '<h3>Your blog has been posted. Go to <a style="color:white" href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';

                echo "seemed to work";

            }else{
                echo "that didn't work";
            }
        }else{
            //include 'header.php';
            //echo '<h1>You did not enter a blog post. Please try again.';


            //include 'footer.php';
        }
    }else{
        //redirect('index.php');   
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of testing which and where your queries are failing is by showing errors:

`if(!mysqli_query($link,$query)) { die(mysqli_error($link)); }` or
`mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));`

Change this in every `mysqli_query` line you have and see what errors are thrown.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

As to my comment below. Do you also debug any errors from connecting to the database (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: It does not display any errors of any kind.

Comment: what is the result from posting your form? Does any of the echo's come back, is the page redirected? And do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on?

Comment: As from the wall of comments in your question. You are sure the query echoed works fine, but it does not get submitted. Did you try throwing an error after connecting to the database?

Comment: $link has an error handler built in it uses Or Die

Comment: @zach, yes added it. The example was taken 1 on 1 from the php documentation.